# General rulefor redirect in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to make some redirects in htaccess. I will explain in detail what I'm trying to do and at the end I will tell you my question, so if you don't want lots of explains just scroll down.

So for you to understand what I am doing, here is an example: if I enter *www.mysite.com/oldpage* it should redirect me to *www.mysite.com/new page*. For this I used:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]

Redirect /oldpages http://www.mysite.com/newpages
```

The problem is that I want to use this for more than one page. So I want that:

```
mysite.com/oldpage/firstarticle
```

to redirect to

```
mysite.com/newpage/firstarticle
```

And the same with all articles. I want to redirect all like:

```
Redirect /oldpages http://www.mysite.com/newpages
Redirect /oldpages/firstarticle http://www.mysite.com/newpage/firstarticle
Redirect /oldpages/secondarticle http://www.mysite.com/newpage/secondarticle
```

But I have a conflict because *Redirect /oldpage* works on every case.

That's why **(AND HERE IS WHAT I DON'T HOW TO DO!!!)** I need to use a general rule like:

```
Redirect /oldpage/(*) http://mysite.com/newpage/(*)
Redirect /oldpage/(any numeric characters-don't need them)/(*) http://mysite.com/NEWSINGLEPAGE/(*)
```

**Instead of (*) it should be any characters,but use them in the new link.**

Does someone know how to make this Redirect for more than one page?

Thank you for your time!

!!!!
**I DON'T KNOW IF IT'S POSSIBLE BUT IT WOULD BE NICE IF I COULD USE AN IF STATEMENT IN HTACCESS...SOMETHING LIKE:**

```
if (adress is /redirect) Redirect to newpage.html;
  else if (adress is /redirect/(some number)/(.*)) Redirect to NEWSINGLEPAGE/$1.html
       else if (adress is /redirect/(.*)) Redirect to newpage/$1.html
```

Comment: I don’t understand your question. `Redirect /foo http://example.com/bar` will redirect everything that _starts_ with `/foo/`, so `/foo/xyz` will redirect to `http://example.com/bar/xyz`

Comment: Yes, but I need it to make redirects like Redirect /foo http://example.com/bars   and also: Redirect /foo/something http:// example.com/bar/something and Redirect /foo/somethingnew http:// example.com/bar/somethingnew and Redirect /foo/otherthing http:// example.com/bar/otherthing. You are right. I didn't give you the best example

Comment: And how is this not exactly what Redirect does …?

Comment: I've corrected my question. Anyway I need to know how can I put something like [all characters]... something like [a-z0-9]... And take them in my new adress

Comment: I just showed you that i have 2 different pages. So if I have /foo I need redirect to page1 and if I have /foo/something I need to redirect to page2/something

Comment: Well then use `RedirectMatch` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
Redirect /oldpage/(*) http://mysite.com/newpage/(*)
```

To

```
RedirectMatch /oldpage/(*) http://mysite.com/newpage/$1
```

Comment: Only `RedirectMatch` allows to use regular expressions.

Comment: RedirectMatch /oldpage/(.*) http://www.mysite.com/newpage/$1.html it works, but I need to check if there is an ID after oldpage. I mean if there is oldpage/151/something to redirect to http://mysite.com/NEWSINGLEPAGE/something   and if it is oldpage/something to redirect to http://mysite.com/NEWPAGE/something. It would be simple to use an if statement but I don't know how to do it here. Need just a little more help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
RewriteRule ^oldpage/(.*)$ /newpage/$1 [R=301,L]
```